# Getting issues while reading series of lines using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read the input which is in the following format.

```
2
asdf
asdf
3
asd
df
2
```

Following is the code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(t);
while(t>0){

    String a = scanner.next();
    String b = scanner.next();
    int K = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

But when I'm scanning, I'm getting empty `t=2` , `a=""` , `b=asdf`, `K=asdf`

Can't figure out the issue. There is no space/new line between 2 and asdf.

I have tried using `scanner.nextLine()` instead of `scanner.next()` but no change

Comment: you are on the same line after `scanner.nextInt();`.So skip that line by doing `scanner.nextLine();` and continue reading your data

Comment: Or just read everything with scanner.nextLine() and parse Strings with Integer.parseInt(String) where you expect numbers.

Comment: @Praeterii I've tried that one too. But when I'm trying to read K I'm getting asdf. Not 3.

Comment: Did you try replacing this line `int t = scanner.nextInt();` with `int t = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`

Answer (score 2):

`nextInt()` doesn't cosume the newline token, so the following read will get it. You could introduce a `nextLine` after the `nextInt` to skip it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Skip the newline character
System.out.println(t);
while(t > 0) {
    String a = scanner.next();
    String b = scanner.next();
    int K = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine(); // Skip the newline character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I prefer:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
System.out.println(t);
while(t>0){
     String a = scanner.nextLine();
     String b = scanner.nextLine();
     int K = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

But note it will throw NumberFormatException when input is incorrect.

Comment: You night also want to replace `next()` with `nextLine()` because all strings are on seperate lines

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks, I forgot to do this.